# My crawlspace has 2 chambers and has flooded recently. Do I need 2 sump pumps or can I connect the chambers somehow?

Tags: pump, crawlspace, flooding, sump

[image]

The red line on the picture above is the "division" between the chambers. The entrance to the crawlspace is from the smaller chamber and there's a cutout to the bigger one. The walls on the left are where the water concentrates more, so I am thinking of adding a sump pump to the bigger chamber and make a hole through the wall at an angle to allow the water to drain from the smaller chamber into the bigger one.

On top of this we will be doing some yard work to prevent the water from getting inside in the first place, but I feel that I need to have the pump regardless to prevent water pooling around 8x8 support elements that are on the floor and potentially damaging water heater, air handler, etc.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest providing a sump pit adjacent to the division wall, then connecting drain pipes from both chambers.